# mongodb mongoose ignore current user from query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on the Edit User Profile page of my website. When a user edits their username and presses save, I want to first check and see if any other users have this username first.

```
User.findOne({'username' : newUsername }, function(err, user){
    if (!user){ //no user exists with this name
        //code for changing current user's name to newUsername
    } else { //a user exists with this name
        //code for returning to the edit page, and displaying error message to user
    }
});
```

The problem is when I leave username the same (and edit a different value, like email). It pulls up my document on mongodb when it queries username, and therefore it doesn't change anything (because user exists!). How can I leave a specific document out of the query entirely?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to abstract your method so that it can be used to change any profile property and not just username?

What you can do is create the query map dynamically based on what field the user is changing.

For example, if your user wants to change their email field:

(req.query.type == what field user is trying to change)

(req.query.value == value of field the user is trying to change to)

```
var query = {};

switch(req.query.type)  // Type is username, email, any profile field
{
case 'username':
    query['username'] = req.query.value  // value of the profile field
    break;
case 'email':
    query['email] = req.query.value
    break;
default:
    break;
}

User.findOne(query, function(err, user) {  // Query will differ depending on inputs
    if (!user) { //no user exists with the type
        //code for changing current user's info
    } else { //a user exists with this name
        //code for returning to the edit page, and displaying error message to user
    }
});
```

Comment: If both username and email were edited, would the query object store them both? I imagine it would look like this

Comment: yes both would be added. In that case, you may just want to run as many queries for as many changes (i.e. run two queries for changing both username and email). Or, you can use the mongo OR operator `SomeObjects.find({$or : [{a: 3}, {b: 4}]});` and if an object comes back, you will need a method to check which field already existed.